# Update Firebase Instance ID on app update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Back in the GCM days it was recommended that every time you put out an update to your app you should check to see if a new registration id was given (since it is was not guaranteed to be the same after an update) when the app starts.

Is that still the case with FCM? I couldn't find any documentation about this﻿

Answer (score 3):

You should check both the current token when your app runs **and** monitor `onTokenRefresh()` to detect when the token changes.

Check the current token on app/main activity startup by calling `FirebaseInstanceID.getToken()`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        if (token != null) {
            sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
        }
    }
    ...
```

The `sendRegistrationToServer()` method that is called in this snippet is something you implement to send the registration token to your own server (or a serverless solution like the Firebase Database).

Monitor for changes to the token by subclassing an `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and overriding `onTokenRefresh()`:

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
```

See the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register

Comment: I'd add a null check for getToken() in the first case as described in the documentation. I've seen it happen in the past, or is that no longer a concern @Frank?

Comment: Yup, good call. The `getToken` can return `null` in that case, since the token may not have been generated yet. I'll update the sample to handle that.

Comment: Also, according to the documentation `getToken()` can block, so call it from another thread, not straight from `onCreate()`

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit confused about that. I haven't ever seen it block. And I've definitely gotten `null` back.

Comment: getToken in the GCM client blocks and could not be called on the UI thread. However the FCM client does not, if the token is not yet available a call to getToken will return null otherwise the token will be returned without blocking and it is safe to call on the UI thread.

Comment: This solution sends token to server on every `onCreate()`. Is that not overkill?

Comment: If you're worried about sending the token more frequently than needed, you can also keep it in the app's shared preferences and only write it to the server if it changed.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to check whether the token was lastest. The method 
`onTokenRefresh()` always called if a new token was generated.

What you need to do is that checking your token was sent to your server when the `onTokenRefresh()` was called.