# Swift FIRMessaging push notification token reset

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently working with push notifications in my new project right now, and I am therefore experimenting with the generation of push tokens. My question is, when do these expire? I store each users push token in my Firebase database, but I know for a fact that these tokens expire/re-generates themselves. So my question is, what is the best way to hold the push token up to date?

Would I simply do this every time the user navigates to their profile?:

```
let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()

ref.child("Users").child(id).child(pushToken).updateChildValues(["tokenid":token])
```

You see, as of right now I am asking the user to allow push notifications right after signup, but somehow it seems that it still generates a token id even though I deny the request. So my question is, how can I keep this token id updated? Would I have to do this in AppDelegate?

Thanks. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly store the token in your database, you'll need to handle two cases:

1. when the app starts
2. when the token gets refreshed

First [get the current token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token) on app/main view starts by calling FirebaseInst`FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()` in for example `viewDidLoad`:

```
if let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
  ref.child("Users").child(id).child(pushToken).updateChildValues(["tokenid":token])
}
```

Since the current token may not have been generated yet, you need to handle `nil` in this code.

Then *also* [monitor for changes to the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#monitor-token-generation) by implementing `tokenRefreshNotification`:

```
func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
  if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
    ref.child("Users").child(id).child(pushToken).updateChildValues(["tokenid":refreshedToken])
  }

}
```

Also see this answer I gave to a similar use-case for Android: [Update Firebase Instance ID on app update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960445/update-firebase-instance-id-on-app-update/39960697#39960697)